# SQL DB with two different tables to combine

Tags: mysql

So, i have tables, they both have an "entity_id" but one of them has an extra column called "price" and the other table has two extra called "postcode" and "city".

```
Like this:          The other:
_________________   ___________________________
|entity_id|price|   |entity_id|postcode|city  |  
|1        |23$  |   |1        |12345   |some1 |
|2        |10$  |   |2        |54321   |some2 |
```

What i want it to be:

```
__________________________________
|entity_id|price|postcode|city   |
|1        |23$  |12345   |some1  |
|2        |10$  |54321   |some2  |
```

But I can't find any SQL code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple join:

```
select
    a.entity_id,
    a.price,
    b.postcode,
    b.city
from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.entity_id = b.entity_id;
```

Or simply:

```
Select *
from table1 a
join table2 b
using (entity_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usng joins
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Example:

```
 SELECT table_name1.entity_id, table_name1.price, table_name2.postcode, table_name2.city 
    FROM table_name1
    INNER JOIN table_name2
    ON table_name1.entity_id=table_name2.entity_id;
```